# How to organize external API database relation keys in a database design?

Tags: mysql, api, orm, relational-database, database-schema

I'm the sole developer of a football (soccer) website. Due to that, I bought access to a Football API that provides football data for all competitions my favorite team is in.

This API exposes what looks like database primary and foreign keys in their results. Fetching data is also done by integer IDs. The query string of a normal request would look like this:

`?Action=commentaries&match_id=[MATCH_ID]`

**How should I store these kinds of API primary and foreign keys in my own database design?** Does it make sense to adopt their MATCH_ID as the primary key in my own Match table, should I store it as a foreign key, or should I do this entirely different? Are there any best practices on external data dependencies?

This one API is the sole datasource at the moment, but that might change in the future.

Comment: In a sense, this is an extension of the age-old "natural vs synthetic" key debate—in your case, the keys from the 3rd party API are "natural" whereas your own keys would be "synthetic".  There are arguments to be made for both sides.